# How can I make an async call with System.Threading.Tasks.Task on a function with 2 parameters? In .Net

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Given function:

```
private static int Add(int x, int y)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Add() invoked on thread {0}.",
        Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    return x + y;
}
```

I tried this:

```
Task<int> t = new Task<int>(x, y => Add(x, y), 5, 6); // 5+6
t.Start();
t.Wait();

// Get the result (the Result property internally calls Wait) 
Console.WriteLine("The sum is: " + t.Result);
```

It cant be compiled, obviously. How do I do this correctly?

Comment: There's two basic mistakes - one, defining an anonymous delegate with multiple arguments requires you to use parentheses, e.g. `(x, y) => Add(x, y)` and two, there's no overload of `new Task<T>` that takes the `Func<int, int, int>` you're trying to pass. That doesn't hurt, though - you can just capture the arguments directly - `() => Add(5, 6)`. There really isn't much of a reason to pass the arguments in any other way...

Comment: There is also a common misconcept with the Task-Framework: Tasks do not necessarily use multithreading! You may need `Task.Run(...)` for long-running operations like disk- oder database-IO. See http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Three-Essential-Tips-for-Async/Three-Essential-Tips-For-Async-Introduction for a great overview.

Answer (score 3):

First, I'd use `Task.Run` instead of explicitly creating a new `Task`.  Then I'd `await` the result rather than blocking until it is completed.  This will require the enclosing method to be marked `async` - you can read more about async/await in [this blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).  I'd suggest reading many more on that blog.

You can capture your arguments as part of the lambda expression.  This part is the reason why your current code doesn't compile.  This is generally more useful than the `Action<object>` overload in the `Task` constructor.  The end result:

```
private static async Task AddAsync()
{
    var result = await Task.Run(() => Add(5, 6));
    Console.WriteLine("The sum is: {0}", result);
}
```

Comment: Error 1 The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

Comment: Error 2 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' does not contain a definition for 'Run'  C:\Program.cs

Comment: Yes, you'd need to add `async` to the enclosing method (as it suggests) in order to use `await`.  You might want to read [this blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) (and many more on that blog!).  `Task.Run` is available in .NET 4.5 - what are you using?

Comment: .NET 4.5.5.. how do I add async to the enclocing method?

Comment: .NET 4.5.5 doesn't exist.  If you are using .NET 4.0 you would have to use `Task.Factory.StartNew` instead of `Task.Run` and you wouldn't be able to use async/await unless you install some extra packages from nuget.

Comment: OK, that might be a version that's installed on your PC, but it's not what version your application is targeting.  Check the *Target framework* in your project's *Properties*.

Comment: omg - thank you very much for this hint. I never heard about that befor. Now  it works with:

    `var x = Task.Run(() => { return Add(1, 2); }); //1+2
             x.Wait();
             int result = x.Result;
             Console.WriteLine(result);`

Comment: That's a start, but by using `Result` you're just blocking while you wait for the other thread which sort of renders it a bit pointless.

Comment: @Charles: actually the Wait() is the problem, not the Result ;) await var x= Task.Run(...) would be the intended effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
Task<int> t = new Task<int>(x, y => Add(x, y), 5, 6); // 5+6
```

What are you trying to do is to define a Task that takes parameters, and passes these parameters to its inner code.

You can use the overload which takes an `object` parameter to pass values, like this:

```
Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(obj => {
            var arr = obj as int[];
            return arr[0] + arr[1];
}, new[] { 5, 4 });
```

Comment: -Error 3 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int[]' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler' 
-Error 2 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Start(System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler)' has some invalid arguments
-Error 1 Delegate 'System.Func<int>' does not take 1 arguments

Comment: @user3037960 Sorry again !! I was not using Visual Studio and writing manually. Try now